# SwiftUI - iOS 16 - Using Binding with NavigationStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I have following View Structure e.g.: Root View -> Detail View -> Edit View -> Detail Edit View

So the user can use a NavigationLink with `(value: ...)` to get to the next view.

How do I pass a Binding from Edit View to Detail Edit View? With the old NavigationView & -Link there wasn't a problem but now the Root View uses `.navigationDestination` to call each View an here of course I don't have access to the `@State`s from Edit View.

My current workaround:
I'm creating a `ObservableObject` with a singleton and pass the `@State` from Edit View on `init()` call. From there on I'm working with the `ObservableObject` attribute (in Edit View & Detail Edit View)